# How get by EF LINQ flattened records but take only one record by field priority if there are duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I prepared a sample data model to show my problem, so don't look at the meaning of the model.

```cs
    public class Job
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }

    public class Task
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Job Job { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Record> Records { get; set; }
    }

    public class Record
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RecordID { get; set; }
        public Task Task { get; set; }
        public int? Priority { get; set; }
        //More fields, which are be different for every RecordID
    }
```

---

`Input:` JobId

`Output:` All `records` assigned to the `tasks` that are assigned to the `Job` with the given Id. Easy right? But, the problem for me is complicated because the result output collection can only contain records with a unique RecordId. If there is a duplicate for the same RecordId, the `Record` that has the highest priority value must be selected (if the priority value is null, it has the lowest value, and if there are more null records the order may be random).

I really care about the app server's performance and RAM, so I want the query to be executed on the database side (SQL Server), and not in strange loops in app code. In my case, the `records` that I will query for will be even several million.

Example:

`Input:`  JobId = 5

`Tasks Table:`

| Id | JobId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |

`Records Table:`

| Id | TaskId | RecordId | Priority | more fields... |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 101 | null | AAA |  |
| 2 | 2 | 101 | null | BBB |  |
| 3 | 1 | 102 | 9 | CCC |  |
| 4 | 2 | 102 | 10 | DDD |  |
| 5 | 2 | 105 | 2 | EEE |  |
| 6 | 3 | 106 | 3 | FFF |  |

#### Result:

| Id | TaskId | RecordId (unique in results) | Priority | more fields... |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 101 | null | AAA |  |
| 4 | 2 | 102 | 10 | DDD |  |
| 5 | 2 | 105 | 2 | EEE |  |
| 6 | 3 | 106 | 3 | FFF |  |

---

I started writing a query, but always ended up with weird loops in C# and an extra collection to copy the resulting data to, and in the application an extra collection with a million records seems to be overkill.

```cs
var job = await _dbContext.Job.SingleAsync(x=>x.Id = jobId);

return await job.Tasks.SelectMany(s => s.Records). ...//what next?
      or
return = await _dbContext.Records.Where(r => r.Task.Job.Id jobId). ...//what next?
```

Comment: The Linq for that is to do a `GroupBy` on the `RecordId` and then in the `Select` do a `OrderBy` on `Priority` and take `Last`.  However with EF Core depending on the version it's possible that will not translate or that it will silently do the grouping in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So every `Job` has zero or more `Tasks`, and every Task has zero or more `Records`. Straightforward one-to-many relations using a foreign key.

You want all Records that belong to a Job with a given JobId. Well, not all Records, from the records with duplicate value for RecordId you want the one with the highest value for Priority (null is lowest priority).

If you would follow the [Entity Framework Conventions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx), the "one" side in your tables would have a `virtual ICollection<...>`, and the "many" side would have a foreign key to the "one" side as well as a virtual property to the object to which it belongs.

Something like this:

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...

    // Every Job has zero or more Tasks (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...

    // Every Task is the Task of exactly one Job, using foreign key
    public int JobId {get; set;}
    public virtual Job Job {get; set;}

    // Every Task has zero or more Records (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Record> Records { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...

    // Every Record is a Record in exactly one Task, using foreign key:
    public int TaskId {get; set;}
    public virtual Task Task {get; set;}
}
```

This is enough for entity framework to detect your tables, the columns in the tables and the relations between the tables. I'm not sure if this is also enough for EF-core.

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many).

A foreign key is a real column in a table, hence it is non-virtual.

### Use the virtual properties

```
int jobId = ...
IEnumerable<Record> recordsOfThisJob = dbContext.Records

    // Keep only Records of Jobs with this jobId:
    .Where(record => record.Task.Job.Id == jobId)
    
    // make groups of Records with same value for RecordId
    // from every Group of Records keep the one with the highes value for Priority
    .GroupBy(record => record.RecordId,

    // parameter resultSelector: take every recordId, and all Records with this value
    // for recordId to make one new:
    (recordId, recordsWithThisRecordId) => recordsWithThisRecordId
        .OrderByDescending(record => record.Priority ?? Int32.MinValue)
        // null has lowest priority

    // from this ordered sequence keep only the first one: the one with the highest priority
   .FirstOrDefault());
```

Although this works, it is not very efficient: during the sorting it will do the part `record => record.Priority ?? Int32.MinValue` over and over again. Consider to use a Select before the ordering:

```
.Select(record => new
{
     Priority = record.Priority ?? Int32.MinValue,
     Record = record,
})
.OrderByDescending(record => record.Priority);
```

After the sort, remove the Priority using a second Select before you do FirstOrDefault.

Entity framework knows your relations, and knows which (Group-)Join to use whenever you use one of the virtual properties.

### Do the Join yourself

Some people do not like to use the virtual properties, or they have a version of entity framework that doesn't support automatic (Group-)Joining.

Of course you can do the Joins yourself.

```
int jobId = ...
IEnumerable<Record> recordsOfThisJob = dbContext.Records

    // First get the JobId and Prority of each record
    .Select(record => new
    {
        JobId = dbContext.Tasks.Where(task => task.Id == record.Id)
                               .Select(task => task.JobId),
        Priority = record.Priority ?? Int32.MinValue,
        Record = record,
    })

    // then keep only those Record with the correct JobId
    .Where(record => record.JobId == jobId)

    // now do the GroupBy and OrderByDescending
    .GroupBy(record => record.Record.RecordId,
    (recordId, recordsWithThisRecordId) => recordsWithThisRecordId
        .OrderByDescending(record => record.Priority))

    // Get rid of JobId and Prority and Select the FirstOrDefault
    .Select(record => record.Record)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you really want to make it difficult for you, you can do a Join on foreign key:

```
int jobId = ...
IEnumerable<Record> recordsOfThisJob = dbContext.Records
    .Join(dbContext.Tasks,        // Join Records and Tasks
    record => record.TaskId,      // from every Record take the foreign key to Task
    task => task.Id,              // from every Task take the primary key

    // when they match, take the Record and the Task to make one new
    (record, task) => new
    {
        JobId = task.JobId
        Priority = record.Priority ?? Int32.MinValue,
        Record = record,
    })
```

etc. The rest is similar as above.

Comment: You wrote a lot more than was needed, because I already have a working application with an implemented model in EF that works. I only had a problem with that one new query to my application. Thank you anyway. I used your proposal from the subtitle "Use the virtual properties". The next option is not for me because I do not want foreign keys in the C# model in DDD, only natural references to other objects, because my domain layer knows nothing about persistency implemantation.

Comment: The answers that I write are not just for you, but also for those who don't know a lot about entity framework. Far to often I see that people tend to use Join followed by GroupBy instead of using the virtual properties. Using the virtual properties makes clearer, more intuitive code, that is way easier to unit test

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple pattern in LINQ for picking the first item from a collection Navigation Property, like this:

```
var q = from j in db.Jobs
        from t in j.Tasks
        where j.Id == jobId
        select t.Records.OrderByDescending(r => r.Priority).ThenBy(r => r.Id).First();
```

which translates to:

```
  SELECT [t1].[Id], [t1].[Priority], [t1].[RecordID], [t1].[TaskId]
  FROM [Jobs] AS [j]
  INNER JOIN [Task] AS [t] ON [j].[Id] = [t].[JobId]
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Priority], [t0].[RecordID], [t0].[TaskId]
      FROM (
          SELECT [r].[Id], [r].[Priority], [r].[RecordID], [r].[TaskId], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [r].[TaskId] ORDER BY [r].[Priority] DESC, [r].[Id]) AS [row]
          FROM [Record] AS [r]
      ) AS [t0]
      WHERE [t0].[row] <= 1
  ) AS [t1] ON [t].[Id] = [t1].[TaskId]
  WHERE [j].[Id] = @__jobId_0
```

If you need to pick the first RecordId by priority for each task, I wasn't able to come up with a translatable LINQ expression.  So you could use a store query, or sort on the server, and filter on the client.  Like this:

```
var q = from j in db.Jobs
        where j.Id == jobId
        from t in j.Tasks
        from r in t.Records
        orderby t.Id, r.Priority descending, r.RecordID, r.Id
        select r;

var results = new List<Record>();
var lastRecordId = -1;

foreach (var r in q)
{
    if (r.RecordID != lastRecordId)
    {
        results.Add(r);
    }
    lastRecordId = r.RecordID;
}
```

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft Your way is not working. It will only return as many record as there are how many tasks. But I need all the records, but no duplicates.